# Get specific string form files to manipulate it

Tags: python

I'm a physicist and need some help with a programming issue!
I have a set of data which contains many events in it, for each event a function is called, something like this

```
for event in range(100000):
    ProcessRegion(region, event)
```

these events occurs in specific regions of the detector called `cells`. Each cell has two channels and I can know the exact region where the event has occurred using a kind of address which is formed by a `partition` a `module` number and a `channel`. There are 4 partitions (LBA, LBC, EBA, EBC), 64 modules and 47 channels.
I have three long files containing further data that I have to use, they are formatted like this

```
EBC64 41 1    1.012327
EBC64 42 0    1.000000
EBC64 42 1    1.000000
EBC64 43 0    1.000000
EBC64 43 1    1.000000
EBC64 44 0    1.000000
EBC64 44 1    1.000000
EBC64 45 0    1.000000
EBC64 45 1    1.000000
EBC64 46 0    1.000000
EBC64 46 1    1.000000
EBC64 47 0    1.000000
EBC64 47 1    1.000000
```

So that you can see the partition and module (like EBC64) a space and the channel number and in the last column the data I want to use. I have three files like this that I want to read from, my question is using methods like

```
def ProcessRegion(region, event):

    partition = region.get_partiotion()
    module    = region.get_module()
    channel   = region.get_channel()
```

how can I get the exact line in each of these three files, so that I can extract the data and use it for analysis?

EDIT:

Sorry for the obscure question, I try to explain it better.

Having the partition module and channel I want to find in each of the three files the data corresponding to it, for example for one event I have partition = EBC, module = 64, channel = 41. Now with this information I want to look into three different files to get the data, so in this case, from the list above, would be 1.012327.
I hope this clarify things a bit, if not I can rewrite it again!

Comment: You must be physicist because i read it three times and still don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm confused, event is a number in range(100000) but you try to call get_partiotion, get_module and get_channel on it. Is the problem opening a file and reading it? Splitting the line in the file to partition, module and channel?

Comment: Seriously what is your problem, reading data into variables? Searching the file for specified variable? Please be more clear on defining your problem.

Comment: Are all the partitions three characters long?

Comment: It also took me a while, but I think the question is how can I extract the event data from each line in each of the files.

Comment: dictionary of tuples then?

Comment: Yes I thought so, is it the better choice to have the three files stored in a dictionary? I is impossible to match the string from the file and use it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, this is what I would do. I don't know what is zero_one, but it seems to be either 0 or 1.

```
for line in lines:
    partition_module, channel, zero_one, value = line.split()
    partition = partition_module[:3]
    module = partition_module[3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you are just asking about basic file and parsing operations. I would do something like

```
f = open("file.txt")
for line in f:
    event = [x for x in line.split(' ') if x]
    partition = event[0][:3]
    module = int(event[0][3:])
    channel = int(event[1])
```

In detail

```
f = open("file.txt")
```

Will open the file where file.txt is the file name.

```
for line in f:
```

Will loop over every input line in the file, since each event is on a single row then each event will be a single line of text.

```
event = filter(None, line.split(' '))
```

Will split up the line by the whitespace, and then remove all the empty strings.

```
partition = event[0][:3]
```

Will read the first three characters of the first chunk (the first block of text before a space), which will be the partition.

```
module = int(event[0][3:])
```

Will read from the 4th character to the end of the first chunk and then interpret it as a number.

```
channel = int(event[1])
```

Will read the whole 2nd chunk and interpret as a number.

The remaining data will then be in (the single 1 or 0 in the examples) event[2] and event[3] (the floating point number)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for line in file:
    partition_module, channel, _ ,data = line.strip().split()
    partition = partition_module[:3]
    module = partition_module[3:]
```

Comment: Note that `.strip()` is redundant when using using the `split(None)` form

Comment: and partition and module may not be separated by a space if I've read the question correctly.

Comment: @doctorlove You are absolutely right.

@JonClements True, but I find `strip()` slightly more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from __future__ import division

fin = open('data.txt')
data = fin.readlines()
fin.close()

for row in data:
    partition,module,channel,value = row.split()
    value = float(value)
    print partition,module,channel,'value:',value
```

out:

```
EBC64 41 1 value: 1.012327
EBC64 42 0 value: 1.0
EBC64 42 1 value: 1.0
EBC64 43 0 value: 1.0
EBC64 43 1 value: 1.0
EBC64 44 0 value: 1.0
EBC64 44 1 value: 1.0
EBC64 45 0 value: 1.0
EBC64 45 1 value: 1.0
EBC64 46 0 value: 1.0
EBC64 46 1 value: 1.0
EBC64 47 0 value: 1.0
EBC64 47 1 value: 1.0
```

Comment: Are partition and module separated by a space?